# div changing the shape and content when hitting footer tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi friends i am trying for a live chat section with some transformation when hitting the footer.Below is my basic fixed div but when it hits the footer tag it should appear same as image.[image]

```css
.chat {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 160px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #002855;
  right: 0px;
}

.white {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
  <p class="white text-center">Live web Chat <i class="fa fa-comments"></i></p>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please send fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function(){


    $(window).scroll(function() {
       if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
          $('.chat').addClass('rotate');
       }else{
            $('.chat').removeClass('rotate');
       }
    });

})
```

```css
.content{
  height:400px;
  width:100%;
}

.chat{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 31px;
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;
    background: #002855;
    right: 32px;
    border-radius: 19px;
    transition:all .25s linear;
 }
 
 .chat:hover,.chat.rotate{
    transform: rotate(45deg);
 }
.white{
        color:#fff;
        text-align:center;
        /*position: absolute;
        top: 47px;
        left: 21px;*/
        margin-top:70px;
         transition:all .25s linear;
}

 .chat:hover .white,.chat.rotate .white{
     transform: rotate(-45deg);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">

</div>
<div class="chat">
  <p class="white text-center">Live web Chat <i class="fa fa-comments"></i></p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for replying.you got me right but that output should appear when it touches the footer tag.

Comment: i have made it  on hover check now.use jquery to change the content

Comment: @muther update snippet.scroll down to botom and you can see that rotate.check if you are looking for that